# Flask error handling: "Response object is not iterable"

Tags: python, rest, curl, flask

I'm trying to set of a REST web service using Flask. I'm having a problem with the error handling `@app.errorhandler(404)`

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return jsonify({'error':'not found'}), 404

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug = True)
```

When I cURL it, I get nothing. In my debugger, it's telling me I have a `TypeError: 'Response' object is not iterable`

I used `jsonify` in another method with a dictionary with no problem, but when I return it as an error, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return jsonify({'error':'not found'}), 404

app.run()
```

With code above, `curl http://localhost:5000/` give me:

```
{
  "error": "not found"
}
```

Are you using `flask.jsonify`?

Comment: Yeah I believe so. I updated my code include the rest of my code with the imports. I even copy pasted directly from your post and it gives me the same not iterable response

Comment: Which version of flask do you use?  I used 0.10.1.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments for the previous answer, that code isn't supported on Flask 0.8, and would require 0.9 or higher. If you need to support Flask 0.8, here is a compatible version that assigns the "status_code" instead:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    resp = jsonify({'error':'not found'})
    resp.status_code = 404
    return resp
```

Comment: This is wonderful! Thanks for taking the time to provide a compatible snippet for those of us lagging behind with an older version!!